# how to create a new file from filemapping

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012

I have open a file with CreateFile API, then I use CreateFileMapping function to map this file on virtual memory, now I change some data in virual memory and want to save them on a new file .( I don't want to change these data directly on physical file and want to create new file ). what function or API in visual C++ can I use to make a new file from a filemapping in visual c++?

Answer (score 0):

There's no such function. If you want a file mapping to be associated with a file you decide that ahead of time. You cannot change the association after the file mapping has been created.

Create a new file by copying the old file and modifying it. Or by creating a new file and writing out all of its contents.

Comment: if we change the filemapping directly we don't need to convert Rva to offset and ... , and if we save the filemapping to a new file it is very easier and faster!!

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand